# Django isn't including the urls.py from an installed app

Tags: django, django-urls, django-apps

I am getting the error below:

```
Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for 'satchless-checkout-prepare-order' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

But I have `satchless.contrib.checkout.common` in my installed apps.  Within `satchless.contrib.checkout.common` is a `urls.py` which contains:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, url

from .views import confirmation, prepare_order, reactivate_order

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^prepare/$', prepare_order, {'typ': 'satchless_cart'},
        name='satchless-checkout-prepare-order'),
    url(r'^(?P<order_token>\w+)/confirmation/$', confirmation,
        name='satchless-checkout-confirmation'),
    url(r'^(?P<order_token>\w+)/reactivate/$', reactivate_order,
        name='satchless-checkout-reactivate-order'),
)
```

Why am I not able to call `{% url satchless-checkout-prepare-order %}` from my template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you included it from your root urlconf?

Something like this in your main urls.py file:

```
url(r'^foo/' include('satchless.urls')),
```

Comment: Wow, I don't know how I missed that.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to include `satchless.contrib.checkout.common` in your INSTALLED_APPS. It's not really app, it's python package which contains common views/decorators for multistep and singlstep checkout apps.

If you look into satchless/contrib/checkout/multistep/urls.py or satchless/contrib/checkout/singlestep/urls.py you can see that both including patterns from common/urls.py:

```
from ..common.urls import urlpatterns

urlpatterns = urlpatterns + patterns('',
...
```

What you have to do is to choose checkout method (let say multistep), add it to INSTALLED_APPS and include appropriate urls:

```
settings.py:

INSTALLED_APPS = (
...
    'satchless.contrib.checkout.multistep',
...
)


urls.py:

urlpatterns = patterns(
...
    url('^checkout/', 'satchless.contrib.checkout.multistep.urls')
...
)
```